# How can I handle internationalisation of text labels in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For our app available in 5 languages, whenever a db table stores UI text, we add 5 columns, one for each language, with names like label_EN, label_FR. The method that builds the SQL then takes a language parameter, which we append to the base column name when we dynamically construct the SQL...

```
string language = "_EN";
cmd.Append( "select id, label" + language + " from myTable" );
```

Is there a better way, without adding too much complexity? The goal is to have a single query that takes a language parameter and returns the right label, but I'd like to get away from manipulating SQL with string methods. I'd like to deal with this in SQL if convenient. I'd mostly like to follow an accepted pattern if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into here is a lack of normalization. Because you have columns for each language you are going to be fighting this architecture forever. What happens when you add a 6th language? You will have to go back and change your table and all the queries that access it. Also, you have already realized that with your current design you have to build up strings and execute them. This opens you up to sql injection.

If you instead had 5 rows of data this would be a normalized design and your queries would be simple.

Something like this for a table design.

```
create table myTable
(
    ID int
    , LabelText nvarchar(50)
    , LanguageCode char(2)
)
```

Comment: and language becomes a condition on the join. Simple. Why did I get in a lather? Who ever came up with the current design?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Case statement to get desired column as below, In this case you have same column name for different language labels.

```
DECLARE @language VARCHAR(5) = '_EN';

SELECT id, CASE WHEN language  = '_EN' THEN label_EN 
            WHEN language  = '_FR' THEN label_FR 
            WHEN language  = '_JR' THEN label_JR 
            WHEN language  = '_PK' THEN label_PK 
            WHEN language  = '_FK' THEN label_FK 
        END AS Label
FROM myTable
```